# Find exact two words anywhere in sentence (array of sentences) elastcsearch 6.8

Tags: json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-6.8

I am trying to write a custom raw query for elasticsearch where i need to search by combination of IDs in a string containing multiple IDs separated by spaces.

The field for searching looks like:

document 1

```
"sentence": [
             "1060 1764 1769 1770 1772 2807 2808 3570", 
             "1101 3402 3403",
             "1101 1764 1769 1770 1772",
             "1001 1060 1099 1100 1101 2806 2807 2808 3570"
            ]
```

document 2

```
"sentence": [
             "1060 2806 2807 2808 3570", 
             "1101 3402 3403",
             "1101 1764 1769 1770 1772",
             "1001 1060 1488 1489 1490 2806 2807 2808 3570"
            ]
```

For instance when searching with parameters "1060 and 1101" it should return only document 1 because it contains both of these values in a single string. 
Avoid using nested queries if possible.

Tried using bool must match queries, match phrase queries, query strings, simple query strings, bool must match filter term query, regex combinations.
Everything returned something, but not exactly what i need.

Comment: Please share your mappings. And could your mappings could be changed? to achieve what you want to do you will have to use nested fields.

Comment: this is the mapping for the field
```
 "sentence": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
```
I guess they could be changed for that property, is it possible to change the mappings only for that property?

Comment: To update a mappings you have to reindex your data

Answer (score 0):

The source of your problem fact that you don't really understand how arrays work in elastic, from the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html):

> there is no dedicated array datatype.

Meaning when you index an array (that is not typed [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#targetText=The%20nested%20type%20is%20a,queried%20independently%20of%20each%20other.)) you lose the ability to query individual items in it due to the fact that elastic "flattens" the array.

You have two options:

1. The more proper solution is to reindex your data, make sentence to be typed [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#targetText=The%20nested%20type%20is%20a,queried%20independently%20of%20each%20other), then you can query each item individually.

the new structure will look something like this:

```
            {
                "mappings": {
                    "doc": {
                        "properties": {
                            "sentence": {
                                "type": "nested",
                                "properties": {
                                    "value": {
                                        "type": "text"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

However as i'm not familiar with your product and needs maybe this solution is not for you, as this might affect many other queries you already have working.

Hence option number 
2. Use [scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html) to filter out documents:

(this script is a quick example i whipped out, you can write a more efficient version to optimize runtime, Assuming many documents wont have any of these terms you query it would be efficient to add a `query` (similar to what you've been doing) before the `filter` action to just iterate over "suspected" matches.)

```html
{
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                 // the must is optional and only here to filter out documents that are not relevant, you should test this on your data to see if its needed.
                 "must": {"query_string": {"default_field": "sentence", "query": "1060 AND 1101"}},
                "filter": {
                    "script": {
                        "script": {
                            "lang": "painless",
                            "source": `                     
                                boolean matched = false;
                                String[] queries = new String[] {'1060', '1101'};
                                for (int i = 0; i < doc['sentence.keyword'].length; i++) {
                                    int count = 0;
                                    for (int j = 0; j < queries.length; j++) {
                                        if (doc['sentence.keyword'][i].indexOf(queries[j]) > -1) {
                                            count += 1;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (count === queries.length) {
                                        matched = true;
                                    }
                                }
                                return matched
                                `
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

As i said before, option 2 is the less "proper" solution and it is by far less efficient. but if needed it is a working one.

Answer (score 0):

1) reindex your data using this mapping for your field. Each element of your nested field ( array ) will be a sentence. As you use only list of number, i will store them as a string, an upgrade could be to use a custom analyser in order to ensure the indexation (but it isnot mandatory if you keep going with simple integer)

```
"sentence": {
    "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
            "sentencearray": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
```

2) query using nested query

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "sentence",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "sentence.sentencearray": "1060" }},
            { "match": { "sentence.sentencearray":  "1101" }} 
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

3) Filter the result, to keep only the matched nested element, add inner_hist in the query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "yourfield",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "yourfield.yourarray": "1012" }},
            { "match": { "yourfield.yourarray":  "1024" }} 
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits":{}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need nested array for that. Here is a working example with phrase matching ( and a big slop ! )

```
# no special mapping needed
PUT stackoverflow-58283078

POST stackoverflow-58283078/_doc
{
  "sentence": [
             "1060 1764 1769 1770 1772 2807 2808 3570", 
             "1101 3402 3403",
             "1101 1764 1769 1770 1772",
             "1001 1060 1099 1100 1101 2806 2807 2808 3570"
            ]
}


POST stackoverflow-58283078/_doc
{
  "sentence": [
    "1060 2806 2807 2808 3570",
    "1101 3402 3403",
    "1101 1764 1769 1770 1772",
    "1001 1060 1488 1489 1490 2806 2807 2808 3570"
  ]
}

POST stackoverflow-58283078/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "sentence": {
        "query":  "1060 1101",
        "slop": 20
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this query returns :

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.16809675,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "stackoverflow-58283078",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "4bsgrG0BWf1JU_OTT9FV",
        "_score" : 0.16809675,
        "_source" : {
          "sentence" : [
            "1060 1764 1769 1770 1772 2807 2808 3570",
            "1101 3402 3403",
            "1101 1764 1769 1770 1772",
            "1001 1060 1099 1100 1101 2806 2807 2808 3570"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Why? Because phrase matching search for tokens within a "slop" radius of token. It does not match across different values thanks to the default "[position_increment_gap](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/position-increment-gap.html)" which is 100.

Have you a maximum number of tokens in a sentence? If for instance, you want to handle 5000 tokens, you can configure a slop of 5001 ( to allow inversion between first and last token, *trust me one this one :p* ) and a `position_increment_gap` superior to 5002.